# C++ map lower_bound causes debug assertion failed

Tags: visual-c++, dictionary, stl

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

I made a class for a map like this:

```
classA
{
private:
    string a;
    string b;
    uint32_t start;
    uint32_t end;
};
```

and I defined a map and a function like this:

```
typedef std::map<uint32_t, classA, std::greater<uint32_t> > ClassAMap;
typedef ClassAMap::iterator ClassAMapIterator;

ClassAMap classAMap;
void lowerBoundTest(ClassAMap &classAMap)
{
    uint32_t test = 0;
    ClassAMapIterator it;

    cin >> hex >> test;
    it = classAMap.lower_bound(test);
    cout << "lower_bound of " << test << ": "
         << it->first << endl;
}
```

then I got this error when dereferencing iterator of the map.

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP110D.dll
File: C:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xtree
Line: 137
Expression: map/set iterator not dereferencable
For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, 
see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
(Press Retry to debug the application)
```

I don't get any error message when I define a map like this:

```
typedef std::map<uint32_t, classA> ClassAMap;
typedef ClassAMap::iterator ClassAMapIterator;
```

But I need to put a greater<> function for purpose.
How can I get rid of this assertion failure?

Comment: `lower_bound` can return a result of `end()`, did you check for that?

Comment: @MarkRansom you should make that an answer.

Comment: Actually I added if (it != classAMap.begin() || it != classAMap.end()) at first, then revised || to && then it worked properly. Thank you.

Comment: @RSahu I'm surprised nobody else came up with that observation. I've expanded it into what I think is a pretty complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lower_bound` will return the iterator equal to the map's `end()` when the item you're searching for isn't in the map, and it's insertion point would be at the end of the map. Since `end()` is one *past* the end of the map, it doesn't point to a valid element of the map. Trying to dereference it is an error. Be lucky that you were running this in Debug mode with a checked iterator, otherwise you'd have just gotten undefined behavior instead of a nice error message.

The reason it changes when you order the map without `greater` is that it changes the order of the map; `lower_bound` is now returning `begin()` instead of `end()`, which *is* a valid element.

To see whether the element was found in the map, you should use `equal_range` instead of `lower_bound` and check that the two iterators are not equal. The first of the two is identical to what `lower_bound` returns.